# omniauth-facebook test with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rspec-rails, omniauth-facebook

I am starting with using omniauth with devise User model. Integration works well but a case is failing.
This is related code from omniauth callback controller:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  before_action :find_user, only: [:facebook]
  def facebook
    process_omniauth_response('Facebook', request.env['omniauth.auth'], @user)
  end
  def failure
    redirect_to root_path, flash: { error: 'Authentication \
      failed, please try again!' }
  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
  end

  def process_omniauth_response(provider, env_data, user)
    if user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success,
                        kind: provider) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider.downcase}_data"] = env_data
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

And the User model methods:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
     info = auth.info
     user.email = info.email
     user.remote_profile_picture_url = info.image
     user.name = info.name
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
   end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
 super.tap do |user|
   auth_data =
     session['devise.facebook_data'] || session['devise.twitter_data']
   fill_with_omniauth_data(user, auth_data) if auth_data
 end
end

def self.fill_with_omniauth_data(user, auth_data)
 data_info = auth_data['info']
 user.email = data_info['email'] if user.email.blank?
 user.name = data_info['name'] if user.name.blank?
 ...
end
```

So everything works fine i.e if a new user clicks on login by Facebook, after authentication by facebook he will come to signup page with pre-filled data but in case of this below case it is going to sign in page after omniauth callback action:

```
context 'when facebook email doesn\'t exist in the system' do
  before(:each) do
    stub_env_for_omniauth
    get :facebook
  end

  it { response.should redirect_to new_user_registration_path }

  it 'should create authentication with facebook id' do
    authentication = User.where(provider: 'facebook', uid: '1234').first
    puts authentication.inspect
    authentication.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

And the stub method:

```
def stub_env_for_omniauth
  request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  request.env['omniauth.auth'] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(
    provider: 'facebook', uid: '1234', info: {
      email: 'ghost@nobody.com', name: 'mock user'
    },
    extra: { raw_info: { age: 23 } }
  ) 
end
```

I got this message:

> Expected response to be a redirect to http://test.host/users/sign_up but was a redirect to http://test.host/users/sign_in

From debugging I got that user object is a new , not persisted when I check it in the 'find_user' method of controller but in case of spec it is a persisted one.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you got a case of debugging to do. Using Pry, I would insert a `binding.pry` right before the `if` in `process_omniauth_response` to see what's going on.

Comment: I did that using byebug, thats where I found that the user object passed to that method is persisted when I run rspec but it is new when I do the login normally using browser.

Comment: Then you go into `find_user`, and `from_omniauth` and then the `request.env` and then ask yourself if the data that went into `request.env` in your `stub_env_*` has persisted. Maybe the request object is not the same and it's stubbed wrong.